# How can I change the background color of the app icon in the android task drawer with a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, background-color

I have an app and its default icon is a flutter default icon. Its background is white.

[image]

However, when i use the app the background of this icon changes to blue.

[image]

I believe it is a default color for flutter apps.

How can I change it to green, for example?

Comment: I think you can set it somewhere in the theme of the material app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a part of your accent color so you need to add `primaryColor` in your `MaterialApp()` widget

for example

```
MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colors.lightGreen,//here it goes try changing this to your preferred colour
      accentColor: Colors.green.shade800,
    ),
    home: StartScreen(),
    routes: {
      '/home': (context) => Home(),
    },
  )
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. But It is a part of a primaryColor. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to change your background or fit your icon then head over to (android/app/src/main/res) and right click and go to `new/Image Asset` then android studio opens an image asset configuration box there you have to change the path and customize it whatever you want your icon to be.

or

If you want to change the flutter app icon or want to add your custom icon follow these steps:

1. Create your own icon using this link (https://appicon.co/) and download the files
2. For android move that downloaded file to your flutter folder (android/app/src/main/res)
3. Rebuild your project

Comment: Thats not his question. His question is how to keep that flutter icon but change it to green at that particular area.

Comment: you can do by --- If you want to change your background or fit your icon then head over to (android/app/src/main/res) and right click and go to new/Image Asset then android studio opens an image asset configuration box there you have to change the path and customize it whatever you want your icon to be.